# How to maintain session value in asp.net mvc core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

How to use session in mvc core 2.0 like use in mvc 5 and webforms eg. "Session["bla Bla"]" and how I use userId stored in session in other controllers in project.
Here is my Login Code :

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
      //  string userId = "";
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var username = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username.UserName, model.Password, false,  false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {


                _httpContext.HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserId",username.Id);
                            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                //return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginWith2fa), new { returnUrl, model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

In startup Section
In ConfigureServices method

```
       services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.Name = "FSession";
        });
```

And Configure method

app.UseSession();

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is not working?

Comment: how to use session value in other controllers in mvc core 2.0. I want that after login I can use user details in other controllers.

Comment: In the future, always try to post a sample of the code where your operation fails (which is the "other" controller) to help clarify the issue.

Answer (score 2):

When you set the Session Key `UserId` like this:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserId", username.Id);
```

You can access it in another controller like this:

```
public IActionResult DoStuffWithUserId()
{
    string userid = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId");

    // do stuff with the userid now...

    return View();
}
```

However, make sure the code file of your other controller contains a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` by using

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

to get access to the extension method `GetString()`.

Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.0#set-and-get-session-values) for a more elaborate example.

Comment: You see my code above where I store value in session. This is account Controller. but now I want this session value in ProductController. When I enter in product controller my _httpContext.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId"); is null.